# difference in seconds between current row and previous row and store the value in separate column using google bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that stores timestamp as below

```
Date    Order ID
2016-05-31 11:46:54 UTC 14567
2016-05-31 11:46:43 UTC 876
2016-05-31 11:46:24 UTC 1345
2016-05-31 11:46:04 UTC 7345
```

I would like to take the difference in seconds between current row and previous row and store the value in separate column using google bigquery.

```
Date                    Order  Difference In Seconds
2016-05-31 11:46:54 UTC 14567   0
2016-05-31 11:46:43 UTC 876     11
2016-05-31 11:46:24 UTC 1345    19
2016-05-31 11:46:04 UTC 7345    42
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you are calculating this.  I might expect (0, 11, 19, 20) for the difference to the *next* row.

Comment: based on question - I would actually expect (11, 19, 20, 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below assumes your DATE filed is of STRING datatype
If it is already TIMESTAMP datatype - you should remove TIMESTAMP() from below query

```
SELECT
  DATE, id,
  IFNULL(TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(TIMESTAMP(DATE)) -   
         TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(TIMESTAMP(prev_date))
    , 0) AS Difference_In_Seconds
FROM (
  SELECT  
    DATE, id,
    LEAD(DATE) OVER (ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS prev_date
  FROM
    (SELECT '2016-05-31 11:46:54 UTC' AS DATE, 14567 AS id),
    (SELECT '2016-05-31 11:46:43 UTC' AS DATE, 876 AS id),
    (SELECT '2016-05-31 11:46:24 UTC' AS DATE, 1345 AS id), 
    (SELECT '2016-05-31 11:46:04 UTC' AS DATE, 7345 AS id)
)
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

Added to address case when DATE field is of TIMESTAMP datatype

To make it simple  - try below :o)

```
SELECT
  DATE, id,
  IFNULL(TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(TIMESTAMP(DATE)) -   
         TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(TIMESTAMP(prev_date))
    , 0) AS Difference_In_Seconds
FROM (
  SELECT  
    DATE, id,
    LEAD(DATE) OVER (ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS prev_date
  FROM 
    (SELECT STRING(DATE) AS DATE, id FROM [test:product.tab1] )
)
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Apprecaite your help. But when I tried running the query with slight modifications, The difference_in_seconds is writing "0" for all the rows. Can you pls help me understand where am I going wrong?

SELECT
  DATE,prev_date, id,
  IFNULL(TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(TIMESTAMP(DATE)) -   
         TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(TIMESTAMP(prev_date))
    , 0) AS Difference_In_Seconds
FROM (
  SELECT  
    DATE, id,
    LEAD(DATE) OVER (ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS prev_date
  FROM
    [test:product.tab1]
)
ORDER BY DATE DESC

Comment: please clarify - what is datatype of date field in your tab1 table!

Comment: date field is in timestamp and if i remove timestamp() and execute the query, I get below error "Type mismatch. Expected TIMESTAMP, actual UNKNOWN."

Comment: Have another question. How do extend the same query if I want order ID also to match with the previous row. 
eg: 
Date                    Order  Difference In Seconds
2016-05-31 11:46:54 UTC 14567   11
2016-05-31 11:46:43 UTC 14567   19
2016-05-31 11:46:24 UTC 14567   20
2016-05-31 11:46:04 UTC 14567    4
2016-05-31 11:46:54 UTC 22455   11
2016-05-31 11:46:43 UTC 24567   0
2016-05-31 11:46:00 UTC 14567   0

Comment: format of comment does not fit yet another question and than answer. please post your new  question and i or someone else will happily answer it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `timestamp_diff()` and `lag()`:

```
select  t.*,
        coalesce(timestamp_diff(lag(date) over (order by date), date, second),
                 0) as diff_in_seconds
from t;
```

Your data may be the difference between the current row and the *next* row.  For that, use `lead()`:

```
select  t.*,
        coalesce(timestamp_diff(lead(date) over (order by date), date, second),
                 0) as diff_in_seconds
from t;
```